# Why partition sorted arrays for finding median?

Tags: algorithm, list, median

I came across an example on the web for finding median of 2 sorted arrays. But I am struggling to understand why do I need to partition it every time if it is already sorted. Also, what happens if it does not find 2 equal medians?

Would appreciate some clarifications. Thanks

http://www-scf.usc.edu/~csci303/cs303hw3solutions.pdf

```
Problem 3 (9.3-8):
Let X[1, . . . , n] and Y [1, . . . , n] be two arrays, each containing n numbers already in sorted order. Give an O(lg n)-time algorithm to find the median of all 2n elements in arrays X and Y .
Solution 3:

Two-List-Median(X, p, q, Y, s, t)
mx ← Index-Of-Median(X, p, q)
my ← Index-Of-Median(Y, s, t)
X[mx] ↔ X[q]
Y [my] ↔ Y [t] 
Partition(X, p, q)
Partition(Y, s, t) 
if X[mx] = Y [my]
return X[mx]
else if X[mx] > Y [my]
return Two-List-Median(X, p, mx − 1, Y, my + 1, t)
else
return Two-List-Median(X, mx + 1, q, Y, s, my − 1)
```

Comment: Hm it looks like those might be implementation details for how they implemented `IndexOfMedian` or `Partition`. I also agree with you that it's missing a base case and won't terminate if, say `X` and `Y` are disjoint. If you are trying to get intuition for why this algorithm works, you can imagine that you are sliding the arrays trying to find the point where they "intersect" (the first guess has `X` and `Y` intersecting in the middle of both sets). At that point you'll notice that the intersection point is also the median of the combined set of elements.